# Qt telephony always dialing the same number

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, telephony

We have an app that uses qt mobile extensions, more specifically XQTelephony. The app uses it to call numbers like "123p5". What happens is that the app dials "123" and then post-dials "p5" which is what we want.

The problem is that if I dial a number like "123p5" and then I try to dial again for example "123p2" or whatever after the pause it always dials "123p5".

I tried restarting the phone, and the result was that know no matter what I try to after the "p" like "123p5" or "123p4" or whatever the app dials only "123".

I've checked and before passing the number to XQTelephony it is always the right number, thus the problems is either in XQTelephony or in Symbian (or both). The code of XQTelephony is open-sourced by Nokia, I've looked at it, but I could not find a way to fix it.

P.S. There is an IVR system that answers the "123" and then waits for DTMF tones.

Comment: Qt Mobile extensions are deprecated , you need to use QtMobility instead , have you tried that yet ?

Comment: Qt Mobility does not have telephony, so the only option is the extensions.

Comment: Yeah , just remembered. Sorry. Extensions use Native Apis anyways, i think native is the only option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time. I finally found a possible solution, though not great :-).

The solution is not to use the extensions, but instead use the integrated browser. If you give it a url in the form "123pp1231" it will work.

However, there is a small bug. Once a browser is open. This want work any more. So once you do one call, the next time it will not work.

The solution to the new problem to add one more "permission" to the Qt, but as it was few months ago, I do not remember it any more. However it is a common problem and you can easily find it on google.